# Space in Volume Name; can you remove?

Tags: hard-drive, symlink, macos, file

I have two drives in my machine:

- An SSD with the OS on it
- a HDD with all my data.

I have a symlink on the SSD for my home directory on the HDD so `/Volumes/SSD/Users/Ross/` points to `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Ross`. The `Macintosh HD` drive is the original boot disk. I'm trying to get rid of the space in the volume name, but when I do I get all kinds of errors. I thought it was a simple as updating the symlink but it doesn't seem to be.

I tried just option-clicking the drive and renaming, which worked but I started to get a lot of application errors.  For example, Terminal won't even open. Also, a lot of the Ruby gem installers don't handle spaces well.

Comment: Is this your main, boot drive or an external drive? External drives are mounted in `/Volumes/{Drivename}/`

Comment: I have two drives in the machine, an SSD with the OS on it and a HDD with all my data. I have a symlink on the SSD for my home directory so /Volumes/SSD/Users/Ross/ points to /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Ross.  The Macintosh HD drive is the original boot disk.  I'm trying to get ride of the space in the volume name, but when I do I get all kinds of errors.  I thought it was a simple as updating the symlink but it doesn't seem to be.  Maybe logging in as another user?

Comment: I'm having the same type of issue at the moment trying to install some gems.  Unbelievably frustrating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can remove it, but you'd need to Reboot for it to take effect.

I don't recommend renaming it - the vast majority of applications handle the space just fine.

If you have a handful of problematic programs, then just create a soft link to your desired location:

```
sudo ln -s /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Ruby\ Stuff /Ruby
```